# date format not correct when pulling from database using linq query

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, linq, jquery

I want to pull a date from db and display it in a telerik ddl. I am able to pull the date and display it, but cant get the formatting to work. The date is display like this:

```
/Date(13496724000000)/
```

Here is my Controller action to pull the date from db:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Date(int id)
    {
        var dates = (from p in db.vwdb.Where(u => u.Id == id)
                           group p by p.Date into g
                    select g.Key).ToList();

        return Json(new { data = Convert.ToDateTime(weeks.Min())});
    }
```

Here is my jquery to display it in ddl:

```
function populateDate() {
    var link = '/Users/Date';
    var dataSource = [];
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: link,
        data: { id: id },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
                var dateOf = result.data;
                dataSource.push({ Text: dateOf , Value: dateOf });
            $("#Date").data("tDropDownList").dataBind(dataSource);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert(result.message);
        }
    });
};
```

I want to display the date in this format: "MM/DD/YYYY" 
instead of  "/Date(13496724000000)/"

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: and where do you use dates list?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan use it to display dates on a web page.

Comment: Is [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) something for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Parse this **json Date**  format and convert it into `"MM/DD/YYYY"` format.

Try:

```
// jsonDate = "/Date(13496724000000)/"

function parseJsonDateTime(jsonDate) {

    var dateString = jsonDate.substr(6);
    var currentTime = new Date(parseInt(dateString));
    var month = currentTime.getMonth();
    var day = currentTime.getDate();
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear();

   var date = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
    return date;

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
success: function (result) {
    var date = new Date(parseInt(result.data.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/",""), 10));
    var dateOf = date.getDate() + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getFullYear();
    dataSource.push({ Text: dateOf , Value: dateOf });
    $("#Date").data("tDropDownList").dataBind(dataSource);
}
```

​